# Under what conditions does the expectation of this random variable exist

Tags: real-analysis, probability

**Under what conditions does the expectation of this random variable $\log(1-|XY|) $exist(where $X,Y$ are iid,$|X|,|Y|<1$)?**

I wish to prove the following expectation inequality
$$E[\log(1+XY)]\geq E[\log(1-XY)]$$
, where $X,Y:\Omega \to (-1,1)$ are independently and identically distributed random variables. However, for this inequality to hold, additional conditions are likely required.

My approach involves setting $Z = \log(1+XY) -\log(1-XY)$, where we aim to prove that its expectation is non-negative. I plan to do this by expanding this random variable and then switching the order of summation and integration, thereby making it possible to $$\int_{\Omega}\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1+(-1)^{k-1}}{k}(XY)^k\,dP = \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1+(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_{\Omega}(XY)^k\,dP$$,then $$\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1+(-1)^{k-1}}{k}E[(XY)^k] =\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1+(-1)^{k-1}}{k}E(X^k)^2 \geq 0$$.

Switching the order of integration and summation requires the dominated convergence theorem, but I'm not sure how to find the dominating function. Please help me.